# Select para Agendamento em Sala de Reunião Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Segue o problema:
Estou criando um sistema para agendamento de sala de reunião.
Gostaria de garantir que não será possível realizar o agendamento da mesma sala no mesmo período.
Sendo assim após o preenchimento do formulário de inclusão na tabela ele verificar se o horário e sala na quele período estão disponíveis.
Utilizando o BETWEEN entre o horário de inicio e fim do agendamento,
Exemplo se já possuir um agendamento as 9h ate as 11h na sala de reunião
e tentar realizar o agendamento as 8:30 ate as 9:30 ele informa que não pode agendar porem quando tendo realizar o agendamento de 9:30 as 10:30 ele deixa, gostaria de saber como posso "reservar" este espaço para que não ocorra agendamento no mesmo horário.

Comment: Poderia posta a Query ou código que você já implementou?

Comment: Utilizei a Query abaixo:

SELECT * FROM salas_reuniao WHERE meeting_room = '$salaReuniao' AND hour_start BETWEEN '$inicioReuniao' AND '$finalReuniao'

Comment: E se você tentasse `hour_start > $inicioReuniao AND hour_start < $finalReuniao` assim se a hora que a reunião iniciar ficar entre um horário já reservado tu vai ter um retorno assim não sendo possível reservar a sala de reunião nesse horário

Comment: Por exemplo, caso você tenha no banco um horário de inicio **9:00** e horário de fim **10:00** se você tentar colocar **9:30** não dará pois é maior que um horário inicial e menor que um horário final registrado, porém colocado **10:30** permitirá pois por mais que seja maior que um horário inicial registrado não é menor que o horário final correspondente

Comment: Funcionou muito bem só tive que fazer uma modificação o resultado final foi esse "SELECT * FROM salas_reuniao WHERE meeting_room = '$salaReuniao' AND hour_start <= '$inicioReuniao' AND hour_end >= '$finalReuniao' "
Muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Respondi a questão para auxiliar os próximos que puderem ter o mesmo problema :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chegamos a conclusão que fazer a seguinte *query* resolveria a necessidade:

```
SELECT * FROM salas_reuniao WHERE meeting_room = '$salaReuniao' AND hour_start <= '$inicioReuniao' AND hour_end >= '$finalReuniao'
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa query resolveu o meu problema com agendamentos

```
SELECT * FROM booking WHERE space_id = 2
AND :dataInicio BETWEEN dataInicio AND dataTermino
OR :dataFim BETWEEN dataInicio AND dataTermino
OR (
    :dataInicio <= dataInicio 
    AND :dataFim >= dataTermino
)
```